# Finality of mathematics

Tags: philosophy

A random question came to me, which looks something like this :

Is there such a thing as a "finality" of mathematics ? What I mean is can we imagine a time where there would be no more mathematics to discover-invent  ?? (can we invent without any limit?)

Thank you!

Comment: Is there such a thing as a "finality" of any other area of study?

Comment: I don't know... not anyone that I can think of.

Comment: I am curious why this question got downvoted. It seems like a legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 0):

Due to Gödel's incompleteness theorem, there will always be statements whose truth or falsity isn't automatically decidable. Besides, there are obviously an infinitude of possible statements, at least some of them should be "interesting" to somebody...